# Bootstrap 3 navbar not fixed to bottom when scrolling in ios

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using -viewport-overflow-scroll: touch; overflow: auto; to be able to use the momentum scroll in ios but I having problem with the bootstrap navbar. When I scroll in ios the navbar stays in the middle of the page until I stop scrolling, then a few seconds later it sticks to the bottom again. Any ideas? The navbar is inside the div with the scroll touch.
This is the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
    <div class="pull-left footer-text">
        <span>All rights reserved</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right footer-icons">
        <img class="footer-icon" />
        <img class="footer-icon" />
    </div>
</nav>


.footer{
min-height:1em;
bottom:0;
background-color: #35AEEE;
right: 0;
left: 0;
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `bottom: 0;`, you can add `position: absolute;` property to make it sticks to the bottom of the page.

```css
.footer {
  min-height: 1em;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #35AEEE;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
  <div class="pull-left footer-text">
    <span>All rights reserved</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right footer-icons">
    <img class="footer-icon" />
    <img class="footer-icon" />
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but when I add position: absolute; it only sticks to the position where the bottom of the page was when the page loaded the first time

Comment: Solved it. It's not possible to have a fixed element inside the -viewport-overflow-scroll: touch. Look at this https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios